# Understanding C++ VK_ hotkey combination values

Tags: c++, windows, hotkeys, windows-shell

I've been playing around with the IShellLink interface, and am confused about how hotkey combinations are mapped.

When only single hotkeys are applied, the return value corresponds to the documented virtual key code; e.g. **F5** == ***0x74***

However, when a combination is used, an undocumented value is returned that I'm having trouble deciphering; e.g. **CTRL + ALT + A** == ***0x641***

What operation is used to combine multiple virtual key codes?

Comment: good question, I was wondering the same thing! Maybe try a bitwise and? I would try myself but I'm not someplace that's possible right now.

Comment: I've tried bitwise AND as well as inclusive/exclusive bitwise OR, all of which fail =(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation for [`IShellLink::GetHotkey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774926.aspx):

> The virtual key code is in the low-order byte, and the modifier flags are in the high-order byte. 
>   The modifier flags can be a combination of the following values:
>
> - HOTKEYF_ALT (ALT key)
> - HOTKEYF_CONTROL (CTRL key)
> - HOTKEYF_EXT (Extended key)
> - HOTKEYF_SHIFT (SHIFT key)

These flags are defined so:

```
#define HOTKEYF_SHIFT           0x01
#define HOTKEYF_CONTROL         0x02
#define HOTKEYF_ALT             0x04
#define HOTKEYF_EXT             0x08
```

So, when you take the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> flags to the high order byte of a word, and combine them, you get `0x0200 | 0x0400` which equals `0x0600`. Combine this with the virtual key code for <kbd>A</kbd> which is `0x41` and you have your magic constant of `0x0641`.

Comment: Egggcellent, thank you =) To simplify for the rest, here's the expression I'm using to make it work:
`MAKEWORD(0x41, HOTKEYF_ALT + HOTKEYF_CONTROL)`

Answer (score 1):

From [IShellLink::GetHotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> The address of the keyboard shortcut. The virtual key code is in the
>   low-order byte, and the modifier flags are in the high-order byte. The
>   modifier flags can be a combination of the following values.
>
> HOTKEYF_ALT
>
> HOTKEYF_CONTROL
>
> HOTKEYF_EXT
>
> HOTKEYF_SHIFT

You can use the traditional [LOBYTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), HIBYTE and MAKEWORD macros to read/write...